# Facebook FQL Query Results different from Rest Query results sent to API

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm using this FQL query to return the different branches of a company:

> SELECT name, location.street, location.city, location.state,
>   fan_count, talking_about_count, were_here_count FROM page WHERE
>   CONTAINS("Hilton") AND strpos(name, "Hilton") = 0 AND location.street > 0 AND location.city > 0 AND location.state > 0

I get a returned list of companies when I submit the query on the Graph API Explorer page. 

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20name%2C%20location.street%2C%20location.city%2C%20location.state%2C%20fan_count%2C%20talking_about_count%2C%20were_here_count%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20CONTAINS(%22Hilton%22)%20AND%20strpos(name%2C%20%22Hilton%22)%20%3D%200%20AND%20location.street%20%3E%200%20AND%20location.city%20%3E%200%20AND%20location.state%20%3E%200%20

I need to import these results into excel, so I'm also using VBA to send a Rest Query to the Facebook API (http://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=).

I'm using the same query in both cases, but the problem is that the result from the Rest Query sent from excel is usually missing a few branches that are listed in the results on the actual Facebook page. Does anyone know why there is a slight difference between the two results?

Answer (score 0):

Are you also passing an access_token with your query from VBA?

When you use the Graph API Explorer, you are authenticated as a user. Some pages with country and/or age restrictions won't be shown to anyone who isn't logged into Facebook and passes the page's restrictions.

If this is a once and done deal, you can copy and paste the access token from the Graph API explorer into your VBA app to get the same data. Otherwise, you'll need to find a way to authenticate your users.